# What is the condensed formula for cyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I can't find it written anywhere and my guess is that it doesn't exist as it would be impossible to write it out in a straight line.

Could $\ce{CH2CH2CH2CH2CH2CH2}$ be used ?

Comment: I don't understand. How does one draw a circle in one dimension as a straight line?

Comment: @Zhe What don't you understand ? Kantura just wants to know whether his formula describes correctly the cyclohexane molecule. The answer is yes or no. For me, the answer is no, and the formula should be written $\ce{c-C_6H_{12}}$.

Comment: @Maurice I'm trying to state the obvious. You're not going to capture a cyclic structure via an linear formula (without cheating and drawing a bond between the terminal methylenes in the OP's formula)...

Comment: @Zhe OK. I see we both agree